# Custom error messages in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

How I can display custom error messages for required field and other validations in jqGrid forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `attr` property of the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) to set additional attributes of the `input` or `select` element used in the searching toolbar.

**UPDATED**: In the comment you explained that you means to customize the validation messages. You can ovewride the valuse from `$.jgrid.edit.msg` (see `grid.locale-en.js` or other localization files). For example you can use

```
$.jgrid.edit.msg.required = "is missing";
```

If you want to make the message more dynamic you can use `custom` [editrule](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) and build the error message inside of [custom_func](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example).

Comment: I don't think you got my question correct. For ex. if we set a Name field as required in editrules and on submitting the form without the name the jqgrid displays the error message as "Name: Field is required" but I want to display my own error message like "Name is missing". How I can do that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But changing the grid.locale-en.js file helps partly in customizing the error messages and if I go for custom functions just for error messages then I have to do the validation logic also that is quite more work. If there is a property errormessage in editrules that easily solves the problem rgt?